# Select records from master table based on condition from 4th detail table

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 4 tables: Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 each one is a detail the prior one for example table4 is a detail for table3 and so on. here is my schema:

Table1:

```
PK1 Integer,
Name1 varchar(15),...
```

Table2:

```
PK2 Integer,
PK1 Integer, -- This is foreign key to Table1.PK1
Name2 varchar(15),...
```

Table3:

```
PK3 Integer,
PK2 Integer, -- This is foreign key to Table2.PK2
Name3 varchar(15),...
```

Table4:

```
PK4 Integer,
PK3 Integer, -- This is foreign key to Table3.PK3
Name4 varchar(15),...
```

I need now to select records from Table1 based on certain value from Table4 for example when Table4.PK4 = 3.

So I tried like that:

```
Select * from table1 where PK1 in (
  select PK1 from Table2 where PK2 in (
  select PK2 from Table3 where PK3 in (
  select PK3 from Table4 where PK4 = 3
)))
```

I got correct results but is it the best/optimized way or there is better SQL I should use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use all joins instead:

```
Select DISTINCT table1.* 
from table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.PK1 = table2.PK1 
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.PK2 = table3.PK2 
    INNER JOIN table4 ON table3.PK3 = table4.PK3
WHERE table4.PK4 = 3
```

I think query engine should be smart enough to optimize your query, but at least from readability point of view the one I provided above is much more readable

Comment: This query is not equivalent, because it can return duplicate values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for noticing that - I updated the answer with DISTINCT

Comment: I want to ask please if I used `INNER JOIN` is it going to match all detail records from detail tables (table2, table3, table4) or only one record ?

Comment: @Wel It will match all records when using INNER JOIN, but later you use WHERE to get only the records that you need, and then DISTINCT is used to remove duplicate records

Comment: As a note:  the version in the question is probably more efficient than this version.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be a bit efficianter than the other answer.
you first do the join and which probably won't matter much since i am pretty sure his tables aren't that big. but with big data i think its better to put the where clause in the ON condition of the join

```
Select DISTINCT table1.* 
from table4
INNER JOIN table3 ON (table4.PK3 = table3.PK3 AND table4.PK4=3) 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.PK2 = table3.PK2 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.PK1 = table1.PK1
```

Comment: I don't understand the upvote.  This won't even compile.

Comment: On every database that I know, the first `ON` clause will generate an error.

Comment: I assume that ON clause should be `ON (table4.PK3 = table3.PK3 AND table4.PK4=3)`  (`table3` instead of `table2`)